# How do I stop my necklace clasp from moving to the front of my neck?

Tags: jewelry

I have a necklace that has one stone as the pendant. The chain on it keeps turning around my neck until the clasp stops at the front of my neck by the stone. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 8):

If you attach the pendant to the chain of the necklace, so that the chain (and thus the clasp) can't rotate without the pendant moving with it, the weight of the pendant will keep it hanging at the front, and the clasp at the back.  Depending on how well you can hide it, a loop of metal our dab of hot glue should work.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on whether this a necklace you use all the time, or just on special occasion an alternative solution could be to use some tape (or blank band aid) to fasten the necklace to the back of your neck. This of course only works if you either have long hair, or have other means to hide the band aid.

If you use it all the time, you are better of with somehow fastening the pendant to the necklace as suggested in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a necklace chain that keeps the clasp from moving next to your pendant. The chain has something called a saddle that holds the pendant in place. Once you slide the pendant's bail into the saddle, it becomes stationary and its weight keeps the chain and the clasp from rotating. It works just like the post described by user3573647 but you don't have to use a metal loop or hot glue to attach the pendant to the chain. This allows you to use different pendants with the chain. It works really well. Here's the Amazon link. It comes in gold or sterling silver.
https://www.amazon.com/vdp/05a49caec1a7470ea95c9de5c8e4aafe

Comment: This looks like a commercial solution, we look for selfmade alternatives. Can you edit your answer to include how to make this?

Comment: Sorry. Was not aware. Along with many other women, I've been looking for a simple, affordable commercial solution rather than DIY because DIY solutions are fairly clumsy and not attractive unless you're dressed casually. Common DIY solutions are to attach a weight, like a bead, to your clasp. Another is to put tape around the clasp to keep it in place. These DIY solutions are common and have been around for years. Let me know if you'd like for me to delete my original comment.